# Is it possible to play music from an Android device to Airplay speakers?

Tags: airplay

I'd like to play my music, podcasts, pandora, etc. on a Libratone Airplay speaker in my house.

I bought the Airplay add-on for DoubleTwist thinking it would let me do this, but it appears to only support AppleTV http://www.doubletwist.com/help/question/what-devices-are-supported-by-doubletwist-airplay/

The reason appears to be that there's no UI to select a device in airtwist.  Instead, you have to broadcast your availability and then pick the device from the AirPlay device.  Sadly, most airplay speakers do not have a UI to select devices.

Is there a way to send music to my Libratone or other UI-less Airplay speakers?

Answer (score 1):

[Bubble UPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp&hl=en) works great, although I don't find the interface all that easy to use

Comment: A link to the app would be good, also have you tested this with the speaker the OP mentions?

Comment: Yup, I am the OP :)

Comment: Gj adding the link and hah, I missed that when it came up, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

you can always try beta version of our AirPlay & DLNA media streaming app for Android. We are just looking for beta testers! Have a look at our landing page: http://streambels.com

Comment: Cool I'll give it a try!